# Why Ffmpeg boxblur working slowly with non square area?

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg, video-processing, pyffmpeg

I've got a problem with ffmpeg boxblur if I want to blur ellipse area. No problem if you have 1 or 5 intervals for blurring, but if you have 90min movie and 150 intervals, it may be working > 6 hours. No problem with square blurring even if you have > 150 intervals, but I use ellipse. How do I do it?

Truncated command (original too long):

> ffmpeg -y -i /data/www/records/streams/ftp/1100921_test.mp4  -loop 1 -i /tmp/tmpmajq7xhk/mask_for_1100921_test_1.png -loop 1 -i /tmp/tmpmajq7xhk/mask_for_1100921_test_2.png -loop 1 -i /tmp/tmpmajq7xhk/mask_for_1100921_test_3.png -loop 1 -i /tmp/tmpmajq7xhk/mask_for_1100921_test_4.png -loop 1 -i /tmp/tmpmajq7xhk/mask_for_1100921_test_5.png    .....   -filter_complex "[0]crop=353:373:685:58, boxblur=20:enable='between(t,189.441341,189.781339)'[1];[0][1]overlay=685:58:enable='between(t,189.441341,189.781339)'[2];[0]crop=353:373:674:93, boxblur=20:enable='between(t,189.781339,189.901336)'[3];[2][3]overlay=674:93:enable='between(t,189.781339,189.901336)'[4];[0]crop=353:373:671:125, boxblur=20:enable='between(t,189.901336,190.001332)'[5];[4][5]overlay=671:125:enable='between(t,189.901336,190.001332)'[6];[0]crop=353:373:671:154, boxblur=20:enable='between(t,190.001332,190.09133)'[7];[6][7]overlay=671:154:enable='between(t,190.001332,190.09133)'[8];[0]crop=353:373:656:183, boxblur=20:enable='between(t,190.09133,190.151327)'[9];[8][9]overlay=656:183:enable='between(t,190.09133,190.151327)'[10];[0]crop=353:373:668:213 .....   -map 0:a -c:v h264_nvenc -c:a copy -movflags +faststart   /data/www/records/streams/ftp/1100921_test.mp4_out.mp4

Comment: Sorry, second part doesn't correct. Actually It looks like a [0][1:v]alphamerge,boxblur=17:enable='between(t,1090.405041,1091.645033)'[1];

Comment: Please Edit your question if something is not correct.